# AWS create new launch template version without parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have a launch template that currently includes the following parameter:

```
        "InstanceMarketOptions": {
            "MarketType": "spot",
            "SpotOptions": {
                "SpotInstanceType": "one-time",
                "BlockDurationMinutes": 120,
                "InstanceInterruptionBehavior": "terminate"
            }
        }
```

I want to make a new version of this template *without* the `InstanceMarketOptions` parameter (to convert the LT to use on demand instances instead of spot) using the AWS CLI.

If I use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-launch-template-version.html and omit the `InstanceMarketOptions` dict, it won't change the LT at all. It seems like this CLI command can only add options and not remove them?

Comment: There must be something else happening. I just tested `create-launch-template-version` by adding/removing `InstanceMarketOptions` as well as other options. It works as expected. Maybe you just look a default version, not new one in the console?

Comment: How do you "remove" `InstanceMarketOptions` in your request? Can you post the CLI command you are using?